# CSS dropdown menu positioning error

Tags: html, css, layout, menu, hover

I can’t seem to track the origin of this bug. http://wwva.org is a site I built the layout for. The CSS dropdown menu is build on a ul/li structure and submenus appear when the user hovers/taps the main link. Everything seems to work just great in Chrome, but Firefox and IE have trouble positioning the submenus underneath the main menu link (jumps on hover with FF, and is misplaced from the start with IE).

Main site: http://www.wwva.org
CSS: http://wwva.org/wp-content/themes/wwva/style.css

I realize this is a specific case, and is less a principle question. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So that firefox jumping thing looks awesome! In a horribly unintended UI way, obviously, but very entertaining :)

Comment: You should try to recreate this in a fiddle and/or show us your code though. [StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) frowns upon "here is my website" questions

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I really just about didn’t post it. Because the CSS is an amalgamation of multiple media query blocks, and the menus are dynamically generated via Wordpress, I thought it might be a pain to recreate. Thanks for humoring me, and suggesting revision kindly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
.menu ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

to

```
.menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

in the various places you have it.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have fixed it. I usually avoid inline-block because of the whitespace issues CSS has when it comes to stacking elements next to each other.

Insightful!

Comment: Yes, I really like inline-block. Anyhow, having the list item inline made it a little unreliable in terms of how the browser actually sizes it. It must have left a tiny gap between li and sub ul in some browsers.

Comment: This answer came in handy, even after using the `left:0;` trick my friend suggested. Turns out this performs much better cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

A friend just suggested adding `left: 0;` to .sub-menu, which seems to have fixed it.